# Using module to define a function that calls another function: Should i use set-delayed (:=) or set (=)

Tags: function-construction, assignment

Suppose that I have a function
`f[x_,y_,z_]=x*y*z`

and now suppose I want to consider a specific application where `z` is a function of `x` and `y`,

For example, suppose I want to consider `z=x^2*y^2`

Obviously, in this simple example I could just plug in `z` and define a new function `g[x,y]=x^3*y^3`.

But in a more complicated example this is not feasible (for example, what if we instead had `f[x_,y_,z_]:= x*y^2*z^3 + x^2*y*z^2 + x^(.2)y^(.8) z^(.1)`). I figure a more general approach is to define `z[x,y]` separately and then evaluate `f[x,y,z[x,y]]`. **I am wondering about using a module to do this**

Specifically, consider the following way to define `z[x,y]` and calculate `f[x,y,z[x,y]]`: (note: this MWE has typo, see bottom of Question for a fixed version)

```
g[x_,y_]:=Module[{zfunc},
zfunc[x_,y_]:=x^2*y*2;
f[x,y,zfunc[x,y]]
]
```

> My question is, in the above code, is there a reason to use `:=` when
>   define `zfunc[x_,y_]` as opposed to using `=`?

I ask because, if I wasn't using a module, say if i instead had

```
   zfunc[x_,y_]:=x^2*y*2;
    g[x_,y_]:=f[x,y,zfunc[x,y]]
```

then I would want to use `:=`, because if I redefine `zfunc` then I want `g` to be evaluated with this new `zfunc`. **However, in the module `zfunc` is local, so I think every time I call `g` the module redefines `zfunc`, even if i use `=` instead of `:=`?**

---

Aside: I realize that a different solution could be to use a named pattern for the `z` argument, i.e.

`f[x_,y_, func_Symbol]:=x*y*func[x,y]`

I am not asking about this solution though, I am asking whether, when using module to define `z[x_,y]` as above, using `:=` is different than using `=`

---

Edit: MWE had a typo (and I am leaving it unchanged above because some comments might be useful to others, and may not make sense if I remove the typo)

The MWE should be

```
f[x_,y_,z_]=x*y*z;
g[x_,y_]:=Module[{zfunc},
zfunc=x^2*y*2;
f[x,y,zfunc]
]
```

I will also try to rephrase my question, since I have not received an answer:

> **Question:**  is there a reason to use `zfunc:=x^2*y*2` instead of `zfunc=x^2*y*2` in the above MWE?

The usual reasons I think of to use `=` instead of `:=` are

- Computation time
- Possibility that, in something like `f[x]=x^2`, `x` may have been defined earlier already (but this can be avoided by using clear or a module or something)

  When using a module like in the MWE, the variable `zfunc` is local.
- It is my understanding that this  means, that every time the module is called Mathematica will **define a new variable** -- i.e. `zfunc$1`, `zfunc$2` etc -- I imagine that this would erase the computation time benefit of using `=` versus `:=`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104951/discussion-on-question-by-user106860-using-module-to-define-a-function-that-call).

Comment: The MWE still seems broken to me.

Comment: @JasonB. Yeah, I mentioned this in the comment (now it's moved to the chat), but OP doesn't reply.

Comment: @JasonB. I think that in the third line of the MWE I meant to type `f[x,y,zfunc]`. I can't see if that fixes it right now, but when I get a chance I'll do so and respond here. @xzczd,   I was not aware of chat, and now is frozen. Sorry.

Comment: @JasonB. @xzczd the MWE should be fixed now (and should be the equivalent to the function  `h[x_,y_]:= x^3 *2*y^2`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a pure function to represent `zfunc`. Like so:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x y^2 z^3 + x^2 y z^2 + x^.2 y^.8 z^.1
g[x_, y_] := f[x, y, #1^2 #2^2 &[x, y]]
```

The definition of `g` is nicely concise and

```
g[u, v]
```

evaluates to

> ```
> u^6 v^5 + u^7 v^8 + u^0.2 v^0.8 (u^2 v^2)^0.1
> ```
>
> much more efficiently than any of the module constructs you show in the question.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer my question, but it is elegant and does the job much better than my example. Thank you.  The only potential concern I have with this solution is that, for me at least, the equation for the pure function is harder to identify than if the pure function was on a separate line (I don't know if this is possible though). (This might matter if say, we had `f[x_,y_,z_,u_,v_]` and wanted to substitute pure functions for `z,u,` and `v`. Granted such a situation probably occurs rarely if ever)

Comment: @user106860 If you don't like pure functions like `#1^2 * #2^2&`, you can instead do `zfunc = Function[{x, y}, x^2 * y^2]` in your `Module`, which is more readable. It is also faster than using a pattern-based function definition (like `zfunc[x_, y_] := ...`). You can speed it up more by using `With` instead of `Module`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will post a (weak) answer myself:

There is at least one reason to use `:=` instead of `=` (at least some times).

This reason would be if the definition of `zfunc` included a condition.

For example, if instead of `zfunc=x^2*y*2` we had

```
zfunc:=x^2/; x>y;
zfunc:= y*2/; x<=y;
```

Then this above code does not work properly if we instead use set (`=`).

Note, however, that if we instead use `If` or `Piecewise` then we might be able to have `zfunc` include a condition and still use Set (`=`) -- I have not looked into this.

There are likely better reasons why one use `:=` over `=` in this context; I am simply trying to put forward one example.